# List all index columns (including filtered ones) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, filtered-index

How to get all index columns including filtered columns?

```
if object_id('dbo.tTestIndex') is not null
    drop table dbo.tTestIndex;

create table dbo.tTestIndex (a int, b int, c int);

create index X_tTestIndex on dbo.tTestIndex (a) include (b) where c > 0;

select i.name, i.filter_definition, c.name, ic.is_included_column
from sys.indexes i
inner join sys.index_columns ic on i.object_id = ic.object_id and i.index_id = ic.index_id
left join sys.columns c on ic.object_id = c.object_id and ic.column_id = c.column_id
where i.object_id = object_id('dbo.tTestIndex');

if object_id('dbo.tTestIndex') is not null
    drop table dbo.tTestIndex;
```

This example gives two rows instead of three.

```
index_name   | filter_definition | column_name | is_included_column
-------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------
X_tTestIndex | ([c]>(0))         | a           | 0
X_tTestIndex | ([c]>(0))         | b           | 1
```

Comment: I don't think there's a straightforward way to obtain this information. It's returned in `filter_defintion` in `sys.indexes` but you'd have to manually tease the expression apart to obtain column names.

Comment: Maybe. But when I try to execute this `alter table dbo.tTestIndex alter column c bigint` I get an error `The index 'X_tTestIndex' is dependent on column 'c'.` I don't think that SQL Server parses `filter_definition` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the catalog view [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx) to find out the columns on which your filter relies:

```
SELECT  i.name, i.filter_definition, c.name, is_included_column = 0
FROM    sys.indexes AS i
        INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
            ON d.referencing_id = i.[object_id]
            AND d.referencing_minor_id = i.index_id
            AND d.referencing_class_desc = 'INDEX'
        INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
            ON c.[object_id] = d.referenced_id
            AND c.column_id = d.referenced_minor_id
WHERE   i.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.tTestIndex');
```

You can then just `UNION` this to your original query to get all the columns.